# When viewport initial-scale is 0.5, media queries don't work

Tags: css, viewport

I'm trying to target several devices, and tell portrait and landscape apart, the media queries I use are:

```
  @media only screen 
  and (min-width : 320px)
  and (max-width : 360px) {
    body {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
  @media only screen 
  and (min-width : 360px)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
    body {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
```

While the page has initial-scale 1.0 it works just fine, but once it is changed to 0.5 (some modifications I make to support iPhone) it simply ignores the red background (portrait mode).

I made a simple web page so you can witness yourself: http://s-goldy.com/viewport.html
(0.5 and 1 are buttons to adjust the meta viewport)

Same issue is reproduced on my HTC One S as well.

Thanks!